# sql server 2012 installation - login failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2012 using a domain account and getting an error message stating:

> Login failed for user

The domain user account is a member of the domain admins group. I've also done the below:

- Open `C:\Users` properties,
- go to `Security -> Advanced -> Change permissions`,
- tick `Replace all child object permission...`,
- click `Ok`.

Could someone please help

Comment: At what stage are you getting this error? During installation? After installation when trying to log in?

Comment: its during the installation, its towards the end. It tries to start the database engine and then fails to login as the user specified

Comment: Try running the installer as Administrator by right clicking it and choosing "Run as Administrator". You might just need elevated privileges?

Comment: I tried that. I've added the user to a group and added the group to restricted groups in AD. This is supposed to allow users to install software without being prompted. This didnt work also.

Comment: I get to sqlenginedbstartconfigaction_install_configrc_cpu32 and then the Login failed error appears